# Recognize peak in specific frequency area

Tags: frequency

I am wondering if it is possible to attach a microphone to an Arduino board and make the Arduino recognize a volume peak in a specific range of frequencies.

I want it to detect a specific peak (for example 0,1 dB) in the range of 1000 hz to 5000 hz.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the signal and look at the power that lies within the
frequency range you are interested about. You could use an FFT for that,
but it is quite computationally expensive. If you go for the FFT, you
would probably end up sampling the mic in small bursts (a few
milliseconds sampled every few tens of milliseconds), as the Arduino
would spend most of its time processing the data.

A better option is probably to work in the time domain, rather than the
frequency domain. If you do not need to know exactly how much power lies
in each frequency bin, and are only interested in the total power within
the window of interest, then the FFT is computing too much stuff you do
not need. A less computationally expensive option would be to run the
samples through a digital band pass filter tailored to the band you
want. You can then compute the power from the output of the filter and
low-pass it:

```
raw_sample = sample_the_microphone_somehow();
filtered_signal = bandpass_filter(raw_sample);
instantaneous_power = filtered_signal * filtered_signal:
smoothed_power = low_pass_filter(instantaneous_power);
```

But you would still need a beefy Arduino if you want to be able to
acquire and process the samples at a reasonable rate: at least twice the
highest frequency that comes out of the microphone.

A still better option could be to do the filtering in the analog domain,
before the signal reaches the Arduino. If you can at least remove the
frequency components above 5 kHz, then the Arduino would only need
to sample at 10 kS/s, and run a digital high pass filter to remove
the part of the signal below 1 kHz. This should be easy enough even
for an AVR-based Arduino.

For the implementation of the filters, you may want to try this [online
filter builder](http://www.schwietering.com/jayduino/filtuino/)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the FFT is the [Goertzel algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm). It is intended to only detect a single frequency, so may not suit your purpose of working with a range.

But it may be more practical and require less intensive processing. Although intended to only detect a single frequency, it will of course give results near a given frequency, depending on the sampling rates and detection thresholds.

I have previously used an Arduino Goertzel algorithm library, but there doesn't appear to be anything available through the Library Manager at the moment; a web search shows [some hits](https://github.com/jacobrosenthal/Goertzel) though.

The beauty of the Goertzel algorithm is that it only needs to keep a small amount of data in memory, so may have some benefit on smaller processors over more data intensive techniques like FFT.

I would try implementing one or more Goertzel detectors across your range (eg one at 3kHz or two at 2kHz and 4kHz) to see if they are sensitive enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could sample the sound from the microphone and then apply a Fast Fourier Transformation ([FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)).

An FFT lets you decompose a sequence of samples into components of different frequencies, usually into "buckets" that each have a small frequency band. You can then have a look at these buckets to see if there is a peak in a specific frequency range.

There are several examples and libraries for this on Arduinos, like [EasyFFT](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/abhilashpatel121/easyfft-fast-fourier-transform-fft-for-arduino-9d2677) and [arduinoFFT](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduinofft/).

*PS. Edgar Bonet's [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/80286/61722) is better; I may have become a bit lazy at coming up with computationally efficient ways of doing things because of my using "beefy" Arduinos exclusively.*